# inverse trigonometric functions and substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My question is why have they taken $\tan\alpha\in (0,\infty)$ when $\tan\alpha$ belongs to $(-\infty,\infty)$

[image]

Comment: The right hand side does not change if we replace $x$ with $-x$, while the left hand side changes sign.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: $\frac{\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)}$ should simply be $\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)$.

Comment: @J.W. Tanner can you please elaborate

Comment: @Andrei can you please elaborate

Comment: Sure. Plug in $x=1$ and $=-1$ in the given equation. What do you get on LHS and RHS in the two cases?

Comment: the left side gives a value of π/2 and -π/2 whereas the right hand side does not change....but how can i prove it as a derivation

Comment: How to prove the bounds on x algebraically